# Read SSL Certificates in a Firefox Extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, ssl-certificate

I am working on a Firefox extension that would display the SSL certificate information to the user.  The actual information would be the same as the one built in to the browser, but I will be experimenting with layouts and other information for UX.

I've been working with Firefox extensions instead of add ons due to deprecation of add-ons in 2017, but this project will be finished before then.

I was trying the example found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/How_to_check_the_secruity_state_of_an_XMLHTTPRequest_over_SSL), but the extension seems to stop on the `require("chrome")`.

Next I tried writing simpler code to figure out how the example works, but this code doesn't have a channel attached to the request.  My code, minus all sorts of printing statements, is below:

```
document.getElementById("click_button").addEventListener("click",
  function(e) {
    var url = "https://secure-website-example.google.com";
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.addEventListener("error",
      function(e) {
        dumpSecurityInfo(xhr, -1);
     }, false);

    xhr.onload = function(e) {
      dumpSecurityInfo(xhr);
    };
    xhr.send();
  });

function dumpSecurityInfo(xhr, error) {
  var channel = xhr.channel;
  try {
    console.log("Connection status:");
    if (!error) {  console.log("Succeeded"); }
    else        {  console.log("Failed :("); }

    var securityInfo = channel.securityInfo;
  } catch(err) {
    alert(err);
  }
}
```

with a manifest like this:

```
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Certificate Browser",
  "version": "1.0",
  ...

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "webRequest",
    "https://secure-website-example.google.com/*"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    ...
    "default_popup": "popup/certificate_information.html"
  }
```

Am I missing any permissions necessary to have access to the certificate?  Is there a better way of grabbing certificate information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wiki page you linked to refers to APIs available in the [addon sdk](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) and bootstrapped extensions. The kind of manifest indicates you're writing a [webextensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) which are far more limited.

Comment: Thank you!  I will start working with a FireFox addon.