# Firefox addon requires chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, ssl, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm working on creating a Firefox add-on to show SSL certificate information.  I only need to read the certificate, I don't want to change it in any way.  I'm trying to use [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/How_to_check_the_secruity_state_of_an_XMLHTTPRequest_over_SSL) to get the code, but the javascript stops running at `const {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");`.  The javascript code is ran from a `<script>` tag in the HTML file.

Can Firefox add-ons still access the chrome module?  Am I missing something, like a permission?

Note: I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809488/read-ssl-certificates-in-a-firefox-extension/39812931#39812931) yesterday, but with FireFox Extensions.

Comment: `const {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");` works just fine in Firefox Add-on SDK based extensions. The problem is probably the context in which you are attempting to run the code. The sentence: "The javascript code is ran from a <script> tag in the HTML file" sounds like where your problem will be.  We need a [mcve] to be able to give you more than just guesses.

Answer (score 0):

This code can only be run from the `index.js` file.

What you will need to do to make the code accessible to the '' on the HTML page is, run the code in `index.js` and then send that data to the script using one of the techniques described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts#Communicating_with_the_add-on).